# Udefined when getting file text in angular 2?

Tags: angular

i need my file text in alert but now its showing undefined.Below my code

```
export class AppComponent2 { 

    constructor(private _router: Router,private http:Http) {
     this._router.events.subscribe((events) => { 
                     Observable.forkJoin( this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/app/components/component1.ts"))
                  .subscribe(e => {this.result =e});
                  })
       alert(this.result);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you even access `http://localhost:3000/app/components/component1.ts`?

Comment: yes i can access this from localhost.. i need text in ts file

Comment: Does `Observable.subscribe` return anything? Can you try without `forkJoin` and do `http.get().subscribe()` instead?

Comment: Exactly, there's to much at once.. try one snippet after another and see how far you will come without errors!